# Android Espresso tests on Travis-CI

Tags: android, travis-ci, android-espresso

I currently have problems running Espresso tests on Travis-CI due to NoMatchingViewException, while running them locally works fine.
It doesnt seem like my .travis.yml has any problems, cause I've checked some other repositories with travis+espresso and it's quite similar.

```
language: android
jdk: oraclejdk8
sudo: false
env:
  global:
    - ANDROID_TARGET=android-19
    - ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
android:
  components:
    # Update Android SDK Tools
    - tools
    - platform-tools

    - build-tools-23.0.3
    - android-23
    # Support library
    - extra-android-support
    - extra-google-google_play_services
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - sys-img-${ANDROID_ABI}-${ANDROID_TARGET}

before_script:
    - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t $ANDROID_TARGET --abi $ANDROID_ABI
    - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
    - android-wait-for-emulator
    - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

script:
    - ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest jacocoTestReport

after_success:
    - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

In my tests I just make calls like this, and everything is fine

```
onView(withId(R.id.email_edittext)).check(matches(hasErrorText(text)))
```

But on Travis-CI I still got failed tests

```
com.tests.LoginTest > test_invalidPassword[test(AVD) - 4.4.4] FAILED 
    android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: mob.prokky.gameshare:id/email_edittext
```

Full Travis-CI log available [here](https://travis-ci.org/Prokky/GameShare/builds/146026318) while the full tests are on [github](https://github.com/Prokky/GameShare/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/tests/LoginTest.java)

Comment: I faced with the same problem and I still don't know how to fix, however it looks like emulator doesn't have enough time to wake up or because of -no-window param

Comment: facing the same problem too. works fine locally but fails when running on travis

Answer (score 1):

I posted the [issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6402#event-742634205) in the travis git account

It looks like issue with creating  emulator for the tests